# Ngx-datatable row detail

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-datatable

I am trying to make the Ngx-datatable detail row work according to the manual but so far with no luck.

I have created this plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/yQv0Gvy8E8k1bqRr5Pxx/ basically just copying the row detail demo from Swimlanes online documentation http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#row-details'

I want to make use of the rowHeight binding as mentioned in the manual:

```
<ngx-datatable-row-detail [rowHeight]="getHeight" #myDetailRow (toggle)="onDetailToggle($event)">
  <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-row-detail-template>
    <div><strong>Address</strong></div>
    <div>{{row.address.city}}, {{row.address.state}}</div>
  </ng-template>
</ngx-datatable-row-detail>
```

and TS:

```
getHeight(row: any, index: number): number {
  return row.someHeight;
}
```

However row keeps on being undefined! What am I missing?

As an alternative I wanted to just access my original rows array from the getHeight function but keep getting rows undefined.

```
console.log(this.rows[index]);
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE - FIX**

What I did to fix it was simply:

```
getHeight(row: any): number {
  if(row) {
    return row.someHeight;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this?

Comment: I'm sorry for this late reply. I was right using it as it is above. The problem however was, that it also sends some undefined. So what I had to do was to sort in the data. I hope it helps. If not let me know and I will see if I can make a better answer.

Comment: What do you mean by sort in the data? Could you update your code with your new solution?

Comment: I have updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do this:

```
[rowHeight]="getHeight"
```

you are actually binding `rowHeight` with the function object `getHeight`.

What you probably want to do is to bind it to the **result** of the `getHeight(...)` function instead:

```
[rowHeight]="getHeight(...)"
```

Comment: While this is the accepted answer, for completeness' sake just this: `rowHeight` does accept a function that will be evaluated dynamically. So the construct was right to begin with, and @KasperSommer 's own solution does pull the trick.